# How to make syrups shelf stable?

Tags: syrup, cocktails

I'm making flavoured tonic syrups, but I want to flavour them naturally with juices, concentrates and botanicals.

I'm working on a "green" flavour with herbs and spices, but trying to make it shelf stable. The idea I currently have is to press the juices from fresh herbs and mix it in with a heavy syrup -- would that create a product that is stable enough to not discolour or spoil for about 6 months?

Answer (score 7):

A syrup can be made shelf stable by reaching the appropriate water activity. Generally, using 2:1 sugar to water is considered sufficient to give you a safe level of water activity of around 0.86, with the only risk being molds, which are luckily visible. So you could start with 200 g of sugar and 100 g of juice and boil that until sufficiently dissolved, but before it gets too thick. A 67% syrup should have a boiling point of 104 C, you can give it a couple more degrees for a better margin of error.

For true shelf stability without molds, take it to 76% sugar solution. That would be reached at 110 C boiling point. This is the "thread stage", but because of the food safety issues involved, I would use a thermometer and not visual recognition.

Theoretically, when you add substances other than pure water, such as herbs or fruit pulp from the juice, you could calculate the exact water activity for these somewhat-wet substances. In practice, I would just calculate a lower-limit by treating everything non-sugar as "water". In this sense, you could start with 95g of juice and 5 g of dried spices, instead of 100 g juice, for the same 200 g sugar, and continue from there.

Do not prepare a simple syrup and then dilute, that's way too watery and has to be kept in the fridge from day one.

---

If you want to calcluate your own water activity, the formula for a pure sucrose solution is

> a<sub>w</sub> = 1/(1+0.79*n), with n = sugar in kilograms

By solving for a<sub>w</sub>, you can find out what percentage sucrose solution you need for a given water activity. As mentioned above, the most common food pathogen bacteria stop growth at 0.86, molds at 0.8, and total microbial activity ceases at around 0.6. You can use a table to look up the boiling point of the desired solution, these are available at most candy making resources, even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_making#Sugar_stages) has them.

Comment: ooh thanks! Technical info always appreciated. I don't want to heat the juice though, that'll dull a lot of the fresh flavours. Spices I can heat in with the syrup -- but dyou think there might be a way to incorporate the fresh ingredients safely without heating them?

Comment: You can't  do it without heating the juice, that's the point of making a syrup. At room temperature, you can only dissolve a certain amount of sugar per ml of water, and that's far from enough to make the concentration needed here. At higher temperatures, the capacity of water to dissolve sugar increases, and you get a homogenous solution which, after cooling down to room temperature, is supersaturated. If you add more water at that point, you won't get a homogenous solution. In the worst case, you may get a partial solution, where the juice dissolves just as much water as it can, mixed...

Comment: ... with the supersaturated part, a kind of two-phase solution. And the sweetened juice part will be a playground for all kinds of bacteria. Without a specialized laboratory, I don't see a way to produce the sugar concentration needed beside heating everything together. Canning is also not going to help you, because you will still have to sterilize at high temperatures, even if you can find a safe recipe. Maybe you could do something with a rotovap (~10 000 EUR), I don't know if the evaporation route works well for supersaturating sugar though. Another route is through adding humectants, ...

Comment: ... but there you would need to pay a professional food technologist to develop the correct recipe for you, since the calculation gets complex, and you are working with rather tight tolerances. And also choosing the right humectant without changing the taste too much is not easy.

Comment: sigh I feel like this is one of those seemingly simple sounding projects where I dig myself a really really deep hole...will try cooking the juices to see how much of a flavour difference there is.

Comment: also I am thinking somewhere in the general vicinity of alcohol-based extractions....or maybe concentrates made with low-temp dehydration?

Comment: Low temp dehydration, if done without equipment (said rotovap) will take way too long, longer than the refrigerated safe time of the juice, and I don't know if it will ever reach the concentration you want. Alcohol extraction is certainly a thing, then you will simply be making a liqueur instead of a syrup.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the flavors of spices and botanicals, you're better off with distillation rather then the above approach, which as you say will cook the flavor out.  The trick is learning the boiling point of the oils you want to capture. There are tables for this, I'm sure. And the other challenge is to obtain and learn to use a distillation set up properly.  I've seen them for sale in antique stores outside of Columbia MO, if you're in that area. Otherwise, check online for a kid's chemistry set. Then, after capturing the essences you are seeking you can introduce it back into the simple sugar.  Good luck!